# Automatic validation in a DataGridView

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding, datagridview, validation

I'm not new to WinForms but I have always "rolled my own" when it comes to validation - and I think it's time to take advantage of the built-in stuff. I Googled around for some basics but I'm not finding what I need...

I've got a DataGridView. I have a (custom) object that has four String properties. I am getting a List<> of them from an XML file.

So when I do this:

```
dgv.DataSource = genericListOfStationObjects;
```

the rows *do* show up correctly in the DataGridView. So the databinding is working just fine - at least in the "incoming" direction.
That's good.
But what I need to do is:

1. track IsDirty on each row (without manually adding a flag?)
2. visually indicate (within the DataGridView) if any of the values in the DataGridView's cells are invalid. (I have validation methods on my custom object (of which the List<> is comprised.) I cannot get those "error glyphs" to show up. I've tried all the SO posts I could find on that...

Thank you very much,
Eliezer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your first question there are two native properties that you will want to utilize:

1. `IsCurrentCellDirty`
2. `IsCurrentRowDirty`

These only work for the currently selected cell/row.  So you may have to resort to making your own if you need to track "IsDirty" on each row. But there is an event that comes with the native dirty settings, `CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged` you can utilize to log all of the changes.  You could also use `CellValueChanged` to log any changes you might need.  I personally use a form-level property to keep track if I have any data edits/changes by using either of these events and if I do, I save the edits before closing the form.

Data validation is fairly straightforward on the WinForms DataGridView.  To get the red error glyphs to show simply set the `ErrorText` of a cell or row.  I also utilize the DataGridView's native `RowValidating` event as well.

```
void dg_RowValidating(object sender, DataGridViewCellCancelEventArgs e)
{
    DataGridViewRow dgRow = dg.Rows[e.RowIndex];

    if ((dgRow.Cells["yourColumnName"].Value == null) ||
        (dgRow.Cells["yourColumnName"].Value.ToString().Length == 0))
    {
        // Set both the row and cell error text at the same time.
        dgRow.ErrorText = dgRow.Cells["dgTxtColTest List"].ErrorText =
            "You must enter a value in the " + yourColumnName + " column."

        e.Cancel = true;
    }
}
```

When the row is validated you must clear any error messages you might have created above:

```
void dg_RowValidated(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    // Clear errors from row header and cells in the row
    DataGridViewRow row = dg.Rows[e.RowIndex];
    row.ErrorText = ""; // Clear the row header error text

    // Clear all error texts from the row
    foreach (DataGridViewCell cell in row.Cells)
    {
        cell.ErrorText = ""; // Clear each cell in the row as now row is valid
    } 
}
```